# Нужно добавить статический метод getBox(), который возвращает пустой параметризованный объект типа Box

Tags: java

```
public static class Box<T> {
    private T object;

    Box(T object) {
        this.object=object;
    }

    public T getBox() {
        return object;
    }

    public static <T> Box <T> of (T value){
        return new Box<>(value);
    }

}
```

Вопрос - как сделать внутри класса Box статический метод getBox() который будет соответствовать условию? Уже все перепробовал, Static не хочет принимать

Comment: `getBox(), который возвращает пустой параметризованный объект типа Box` - параметризованный каким типом?

Comment: Требования:
1. Класс должен быть параметризован T.
2. Поле должно быть приватным с именем object.
3. Класс должен иметь публичный модификатор доступа.
4. Класс должен иметь публичный статический метод getBox().
5. метод getBox() должен работать согласно условию..
6. Класс Box должен быть статическим.

Задание оторвано от реальности. Параметризирован типом Т

Comment: Понятнее не стало)  `Box<T> getBox()` - какой тип должен вместо T быть? Точнее, как java должна определить, какой конкретный тип подставить вместо T? Именно в таком виде задание не выполнимо.

Comment: Очевидно что тип T предопределен в другом классе, доступа к которому нет

Comment: Если написать, к примеру `Box<String> box = Box.of(null)` собственно и получится искомое.